# Document Set allowed content types

Tags: content-type, document-set

I want to get all Content types of Document Set. 
I've used documentSet.ContentTypeTemplate.AllowedContentTypes.But it does not allow me to enumerate through.
How to access the Content Types of Document Set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DocumentSetTemplate.AllowedContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentsettemplate.allowedcontenttypes%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property returns [AllowedContentTypeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.allowedcontenttypecollection%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object:

```
public class AllowedContentTypeCollection : IEnumerable<SPContentTypeId>, 
    IEnumerable
```

How to iterate through [DocumentSetTemplate.AllowedContentTypes]:

```
var ctIds = ds.ContentTypeTemplate.AllowedContentTypes;


 //1
 foreach (SPContentTypeId ctId in ctIds)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ctId); //print Content Type Id
 }


 //2
 var enumerator = ctIds.GetEnumerator();
 while (enumerator.MoveNext())
 {
     var ctId = enumerator.Current; 
     Console.WriteLine(ctId);
 }
```